# Angular 5 tslint error when using a class component selector

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a component that uses the following selector: `li.my-component`.  The linter throws an error on this. Is there a setting for the `component-selector` rule in tslint that will accept this as the component selector?

As a general question where is the documentation on what the allowed settings are for these custom tslint rules.

Comment: The documentation is on the codelyzer site, e.g. http://codelyzer.com/rules/component-selector/